# Spring MVC + JSP: значение атрибута из контроллера не отображается в конечном html

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

Пытаюсь нааписать простейшее прложение с Spring MVC (типа Hello, World!).
Вроде всё делаю по учебнику. Но и итоге отображается html страница на которой вместо значений атрибутов модели, переданых из контроллера, отображаются ${<название паратметра>}.
Т.е., например, в контролле пишу:

```
modelAndView.addObject("body", "Have a nice day!");
```

в JSP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>${title}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    This is the body: ${body}
  </body>
</html>
```

В результате выводится страница:

> This is the body: ${body}

Облазил почти весь интернет, не могу найти решение.
В контроллер программа попадает и нужные значения возвращает.

Вот код контроллера полностью:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView main() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.addObject("title", "Hello!");
        modelAndView.addObject("body", "Have a nice day!");
        modelAndView.setViewName("index");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Начнем с простого. Я не знаю какую версию сервлетов вы используете. Если ниже 2.4, то в самом верху вьюшки у вас должно быть нечто следующее 
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" isELIgnored="false" %>

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно, заработало. Осталось только понять, что это значит, и почему про это не написано в туториале :)

Comment: Я оформлю это как ответ и поясню

Comment: Спасибо!
У меня правда использовались сервлеты версии 2.3:

<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, используется версия сервлетов ниже 2.4. В таком случае в самом верху JSP надо добавить что-то вроде

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" isELIgnored="false" %>
```

Основное тут - это `isELIgnored="false"` что является прямым указанием рассчитывать выражения написанные на Expression Language (то что помещено в конструкциях ${} или #{}).
Если версия 2.4 то is ELIgnored не нужен, там он по дефолту false

Answer (score -1):

isELIgnored="false" помогло

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Это обрезанный дубликат комментария и существующего ответа четырехлетней давности.